# Remove color of tab characters in Sublime Text 3 with Fortran

Tags: colors, tabs, fortran, sublimetext3

I am using the Fortran text highlighting package for Sublime text 3, how can I remove the color from the tab characters? (see the pic)

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't a tab is not a legal character in the place you use it. It is one of the additional characters as mentioned in the Fortran standard (paragraph numbers might be different for the different standards): Additional characters may be representable in the processor, but may appear only in comments (6.3.2.3, 6.3.3.2), character constants (7.4.4), input/output records (12.2.2), and character string edit descriptors (13.3.2).

Comment: The highlight is telling you that the syntax is invalid (because tabs are not valid it would appear, though I'm not a Fortran guy). If that's the case, short of modifying your color scheme to not highlight invalid code (which generally isn't a good idea) your best bet would probably be to turn on `translate_tabs_to_spaces` in your settings (or in the Fortran specific settings) so that tabs don't appear.